# Unmanaged packages deployment vs Salesforce DX

Tags: unmanaged-package, salesforcedx

A common way to develop unmanaged packages is to place them on Github so that they can be deployed with the ANT tool or the Github to Salesforce deployment tool.

How does Salesforce DX change the scenario? Are there additional way to develop and distribute unmanaged packages?

Answer (score 1):

DX does not change anything except it eliminates need for ANT tool and assumes every developer will have DX CLI installed.

If you are familiar with DX , you will just use DX to create your project build and test and then use convert commands to create a metadata API for deployment to an org from where you generate unmanaged package .

On the git repository you can specify what DX commands a developer needs to use to deploy to the production or sandbox org or to pull into a scratch org .

For public repositories there are open source projects to deploy the code to the scratch org using one click buttons like this [one](http://www.wadewegner.com/2017/09/deploy-to-salesforce-dx/)

SDFX is just new way of thinking about source driven development and nothing changes at the core of it .

Comment: i am creating a package.xml based on the git dff and generating the `src` components to migrate from one sandbox to another sandbox and eventually to the prod. is this an unmannaged package? we are not an ISV and we work most with the 'SALES' app in sf

Comment: Yes so best way to do is create an unnmanaged package and pull all code by package name and a package xml is automatically generated .Does not matter DX is for even SI

Comment: i am more trying to understand the terminologies: "unmanaged Vs managed".. although i have read about it, but it all talks w.r.t ISV's. So i was kind of thinking, if the package (src folder and its contents) that i generate for our local deployment is also refered to as 'unmanaged' package. And can you please elaborate more on this, "create an unnmanaged package and pull all code by package name and a package xml is automatically generated "  .. thanks

Comment: Could you reach me at mail Id in my profile?